# if-let statement doesn't unwrap optional

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

I've run across something in my code that seems curious and was wondering if there is a straightforward explanation for this behavior. Given the following statement:

```
    if let tabBarController = topViewController as? UITabBarController {
        for subcontroller in tabBarController.viewControllers! {
            println(subcontroller.view)
            if let subcontrollerView = subcontroller.view {
                println(subcontrollerView)
                println(subcontrollerView!)
                if subcontrollerView!.window != nil && subcontroller.isViewLoaded() {
                    topViewController = subcontroller as? UIViewController
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now as far as I know the if-let statement should unwrap the conditional for me--but this is not the behavior exhibited here. I cannot access the `window` property of `subcontrollerView` unless I unwrap the optional again. The x-code console returns the following:

```
Optional(<UILayoutContainerView: 0x7fbccd44e7f0; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fbccacdde90>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fbccd440e30>>)
Optional(<UILayoutContainerView: 0x7fbccd44e7f0; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fbccacdde90>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fbccd440e30>>)
<UILayoutContainerView: 0x7fbccd44e7f0; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fbccacdde90>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fbccd440e30>>
```

The unwrapped optional and the if-let constant are the same. Why?

Comment: Nothing will be unwrapped if your optional is nil.

Comment: right, but look at the console output--it's not nil

Comment: looks like a bug to me, can you isolate this in a tiny project? If so, you could post it here and we could take a look at it ourselves. If there still seems to be an issue that project would be great for submitting a radar to Apple.

Comment: Can you do a clean (full i.e. option clean) of your project and recompile?

Comment: Just cleaned the project and recompiled--issue wasn't resolved. I'll put together a miniproject and post it momentarily.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is `AnyObject`. (When in doubt, your problem is always `AnyObject`; it is an evil type that should be avoided as much as possible. The only thing worse is `AnyObject?`.)

The trouble is that `tabBarController.viewControllers` returns `[AnyObject]?`, and optional promotion probably causes things to go sideways. It's likely promoting an `AnyObject?` to an `AnyObject??` and then getting confused. This is somewhat a compiler bug, but also just the madness that comes with `AnyObject`. So the answer is to get rid of it as quickly as you can.

Instead of this:

```
for subcontroller in tabBarController.viewControllers! {
```

You want this:

```
if let viewControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers as? [UIViewController] {
   for subcontroller in viewControllers {
```

So the full code is this:

```
if let tabBarController = topViewController as? UITabBarController {
    if let viewControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers as? [UIViewController] {
        for subcontroller in viewControllers {
            if let subcontrollerView = subcontroller.view {
                if subcontrollerView.window != nil && subcontroller.isViewLoaded() {
                    topViewController = subcontroller
                    break;
                } } } } }
```

But we can do better. First, optional chaining is often a better way to manage multiple if-lets, and when it doesn't work well, we can use Swift 1.2's new multi-if-let syntax to get this:

```
if let tabBarController = topViewController as? UITabBarController,
    viewControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers as? [UIViewController] {
        for subcontroller in viewControllers {
            if subcontroller.view?.window != nil && subcontroller.isViewLoaded() {
                topViewController = subcontroller
                break;
            } } }
```

Comment: What an excellent answer. @Rob - why do Apple use AnyObject for the return type of abBarController.viewControllers. Why not just return a [UIViewController] array - I guess because the viewControllers will all be subclasses of UIViewController?... still this seems an ugly solution

Comment: It's because we're still transitioning to Swift interfaces. The ObjC interface returns an `NSArray`, which provides no type information. The automatic conversion script that Apple is obviously using translates into `[AnyObject]?` in Swift. In order to make it something else, the Apple developers have to hand-modify the API. They've been doing that step-by-step in each release, but there are lots of pieces that haven't been fixed yet.

Comment: indeed... guess there isn't really a solution as the ViewController subclass types are all likely to be different in a tabBarController.

Comment: Yes, thanks very much for clearing this confusion up, rob.  If anyone is interested in the source code, it's posted here: https://github.com/kellanburket/swift_optionals_bug_test.

Comment: Wait! Is Optional AnyObject?

Comment: Sorry; `Optional` is `Any`, not `AnyObject`.  But I still suspect that the underlying compiler bug is an Optional promotion of the `AnyObject` (because I've seen a lot of that kind of stuff whenever `AnyObject?` could happen). Swift will automatically promote any type to an optional version of that type when it thinks it needs to, and I think that's what is happening here. (It's not correct; but AnyObject tends to confuse the compiler, especially when mixed with Optionals.)

Comment: Removed the confusing portion.