# swift if-let doesn't unwrap optional NSDictionary

Tags: ios, swift, option-type, unwrap

In [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28530652/if-let-statement-doesnt-unwrap-optional/33448220#33448220), the advice is to type cast `[AnyObject]` to a typed array, but in my case, the return value is a singular `AnyObject` down castable to a singular `JSONObjectWithData`:

```
// ObjC def: public class func JSONObjectWithData(data: NSData, options opt: NSJSONReadingOptions) throws -> AnyObject
if let jsonResult = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary {
     if let results = jsonResult!["results"] as? NSArray { // ! needed or compile error
     }
}
```

How to make Swift automatically unwrap the `jsonResult`?

UPDATE: Here is a better example to show the problem:

```
func intOrThrow(arg: Int) throws -> AnyObject? {
    if arg < 0 {
        throw NSError(domain: "test", code: 400, userInfo: nil)
    } else if arg == 0 {
        return ["ZERO"]
    } else if arg > 1000 {
        return nil
    }
    return arg * 2
}

func strOrNil(arg: Int) -> String? {
    if arg < 0 ||  arg > 1000 {
        return nil
    }
    return "NUMBER\(arg)"
}

print("before intOrThrow(100) and optional unwrap")
if let x = try? self.intOrThrow(100) as? [String], // incorrect type
results = x?.count {
    print("count is \(results). x is \(x)")
}
print("before intOrThrow(0) and optional unwrap")
if let x = try? self.intOrThrow(0) as? [String], // good type
results = x?.count {
    print("count is \(results). x is \(x)")
}
print("before intOrThrow(-100) and optional unwrap")
if let x = try? self.intOrThrow(-100) as? [String], // throw
results = x?.count {
    print("count is \(results). x is \(x)")
}
print("before intOrThrow(1111) and optional unwrap")
if let x = try? self.intOrThrow(1111) as? [String], // nil
results = x?.count {
    print("count is \(results). x is \(x)")
}

print("before intOrThrow(200) and block")
if let x = try? self.intOrThrow(200) as? [String] { // incorrect type
    print("count is \(x?.count). x is \(x)") // still require ! or ?, else compile error
}
print("before intOrThrow(0) and block")
if let x = try? self.intOrThrow(0) as? [String] { // good type
    print("count is \(x?.count). x is \(x)") // still require ! or ?, else compile error
}
print("before intOrThrow(-200) and block")
if let x = try? self.intOrThrow(-200) as? [String] { // throw
    print("count is \(x!.count). x is \(x)") // still require ! or ?, else compile error
}
print("before intOrThrow(2222) and block")
if let x = try? self.intOrThrow(2222) as? [String] { // nil
    print("count is \(x?.count). x is \(x)") // still require ! or ?, else compile error
}
print("done intOrThrow")

print("before strOrNil(3333) and block")
if let x = self.strOrNil(2222) { // nil, no type cast
    print("count is \(x.lowercaseString). x is \(x)") // don't require ! or ?
}
print("done strOrNil")
```

```
outputs:
    before intOrThrow(100) and optional unwrap
    before intOrThrow(0) and optional unwrap
    count is 1. x is Optional(["ZERO"])
    before intOrThrow(-100) and optional unwrap
    before intOrThrow(1111) and optional unwrap
    before intOrThrow(200) and block
    count is nil. x is nil
    before intOrThrow(0) and block
    count is Optional(1). x is Optional(["ZERO"])
    before intOrThrow(-200) and block
    before intOrThrow(2222) and block
    count is nil. x is nil
    done intOrThrow
    before strOrNil(3333) and block
    done strOrNil
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there's a few things going on here that I would change and I'll go through and explain why I personally would do it different.

Let's start with `try?`. The difference between `try?` and plain old `try` is that `try?` will either succeed or return `nil` whereas `try` promises it will succeed or throw some error. What that does is change the return type, in this case `JSONObjectWithData` goes from returning `AnyObject` to `AnyObject?`.

```
do {
    let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, .MutableContainers)
} catch {} //catch and report on the error
```

This way, `jsonResult` is guaranteed to exist as `AnyObject` if an error isn't thrown. Then you can do `if let jsonResult = jsonResult["results"] as? NSArray`.
Which btw, I wouldn't use `NSArray` if you can help it, try to stick to Swift native types as much as possible (something like `as? [AnyObject]` is fine).

Now your code looks like this:

```
var data: NSData! = NSData(base64EncodedString: "SGVsbG8gd29ybGQh", options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.IgnoreUnknownCharacters)
do {
let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)
    if let results = jsonResult["results"] as? [AnyObject] {
        print(results)
    } else {
        print("how did this happen?")
    }
} catch {

}
```

Note: You also don't need the downcast to `[AnyObject]` for it to compile but then `results` will be `AnyObject`

Now I'm not a huge fan of `do catch` in this situation. A much better way to go about this imo is:

```
guard let data = NSData(base64EncodedString: "SGVsbG8gd29ybGQh", options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.IgnoreUnknownCharacters),
    jsonResult = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers),
    result = jsonResult["results"] as? [AnyObject] else {
    return 
}
```

Now it's one statement, compiles just fine, and all three optionals are unwrapped in one statement. If the `guard` statement passes, `data`, `jsonResult`, and `results` will all be populated. If any fail, the else will be called and the statement returns. In `guard` statements and also `if let` statements, you can unwrap a variable and if it passes, use it down the chain of unwraps, just like how my `guard` statement first unwraps `data` then `jsonResult` which uses the wrapped data, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Though I'm not curios why the `if let` doesn't quite work. You are right that it has to do with the `try?`. It looks like a compiler (or language definition) bug to me though, since if the `try?` produce `nil`, the `if let` block should be skipped as for non-try usages.

Comment: typo: "I'm mostly curios ..."

Comment: As to why your original code didn't compile? Do you mean without the `as? NSArray` cast?

Comment: No, it only complaint the `jsonResult` must be unwrapped with `~` or `?`.